# MySQL join different table on case

Tags: mysql, sql, join, case

I'm trying to join a different table depended on the value of a "task_type" column

What is wrong with the syntax?
Thanks.

```
SELECT t.*,s.task_name
    CASE
    WHEN t.task_type = 0 THEN
    LEFT JOIN scheduler_tasks s ON s.scheduler_task_id = t.task_id
    WHEN t.task_type = 1 THEN 
    LEFT JOIN invoice_tasks s ON s.uid = t.task_id 
    END 
    FROM task_timings t 
    WHERE t.account_id = ? AND t.start_date >= DATE(?) AND t.start_date <= DATE(?)
```

Comment: can you show error?

Comment: `FROM` must be before `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: @aendeerei it was before, same error   You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN t.task_type = 0 THEN LEFT JOIN scheduler_tasks s ON s.scheduler_task' at line 2, driver error code is 1064

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you want this:

```
SELECT t.*,
       COALESCE(s.task_name, i.task_name) as task_name
FROM task_timings t LEFT JOIN
     scheduler_tasks s
     ON s.scheduler_task_id = t.task_id AND 
        t.task_type = 0 LEFT JOIN
     invoice_tasks i
     ON i.uid = t.task_id AND t.task_type = 1
WHERE t.account_id = ? AND t.start_date >= DATE(?) AND
      t.start_date <= DATE(?);
```

Comment: Thanks! one small adjustment was ON s.uid - needs to be ON i.uid

Answer (score 0):

Can you try like this :

```
SELECT t.*,s.task_name FROM task_timings t 
CASE
WHEN t.task_type = 0 THEN
LEFT JOIN scheduler_tasks s ON s.scheduler_task_id = t.task_id
WHEN t.task_type = 1 THEN 
LEFT JOIN invoice_tasks s ON s.uid = t.task_id 
END 
    WHERE t.account_id = ? AND t.start_date >= DATE(?) AND t.start_date <= DATE(?)
```

Comment: Same - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'CASE WHEN t.task_type = 0 THEN LEFT JOIN scheduler_tasks s ON s.scheduler_task' at line 2, driver error code is 1064

Comment: Bro. Did you even try the query or you just copied and pasted?